# Retornar um valor de uma coluna MYSQL/JAVA

Tags: java, mysql, banco-de-dados

Tenho o seguinte código pra armazenar o valor máximo de uma coluna em uma váriavel inteira codigomax:

```
cf = new ConnectionFactory().getConexao();
int codigomax = 0;
try {
    stmt1 = cf.prepareStatement("SELECT max(id_endereço) as max_id_endereço from endereço");
    rs1 = stmt1.executeQuery("SELECT max(id_endereço) as max_id_endereço from endereço");
    if (rs1.next()) {
        codigomax = rs1.getInt("max_id_endereço");
    }
}
catch (SQLException ex){
}
```

Porém quando verifico a varíavel, ela sempre está com o valor que foi inicializada
PS: A coluna em questão tem dados!

Answer (score 1):

Opa, acho que tem algo estranho no seu código.

- O método executeQuery não tem parâmetros [Documentação do PreparedStatement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeQuery())

```java
stmt1 = cf.prepareStatement("SELECT max(id_endereço) as max_id_endereço from endereço");
rs1 = stmt1.executeQuery();
```

Outra coisa que pode dar erros são os caracteres não-ascii. Eu sei que a maioria das coisas hoje em dia funciona com eles, mas vale a pena tentar sem eles.

então fica assim:

```java
cf = new ConnectionFactory().getConexao();
int codigomax = 0;
try {
    stmt1 = cf.prepareStatement("SELECT max(id_endereço) as max_id_endereco from endereço"); //sem ç
    rs1 = stmt1.executeQuery();
    if (rs1.next()) {
        codigomax = rs1.getInt("max_id_endereco"); //sem ç
    }            
} catch (SQLException ex) {}
```